Unable to run the docker and get the error of wsl
I installed the Docker some time ago and with it I installed all the requirements of wsl now I get the error that when I open the Docker app I get the error that Docker desktopwsl update failed which is shown below in the signature and in my Docker app nothing is visible no containers or anything else is visible

i tried alot of things but got nothing

Please don't put the images as links, upload them to the post. You wrote "I tried a lot of things", please provide this information, what did you do? what are the results of it?

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Also, as specified in the previous comment, edit your question and include all relevant details:  code, errors etc.  Thank you

Hi Ayaan Mehdi and welcome to StackOverflow!
The error message most likely tells you directly what to do: update your wsl.
Microsoft updated the WSL to version 2 some time ago. You should be able to update following these steps:
Go into a Powershell or Cmd Terminal and execute
wsl -l -v

It will display all the running wsl instances in a table format. For me it looks something like this:

To update the underlying wsl version you can execute
wsl --set-version <NAME> 2 

For example, if my Ubuntu-22.04 would be version 1 I would execute
wsl --set-version Ubuntu-22.04 2

There should be an output similar to Conversion complete
If none if this works, you need to set the default version for new installations to use the newer wsl version. Execute
wsl --set-default-version 2

and then reinstall Docker Desktop, explicitely enabling the WSL2 Docker Backend as described by the Docker Documentation

If you're on Windows
Solution 1: Update WSL
Run wsl --update on your command line.
Solution 2: Disable and reinstall WSL
Uninstall through "Windows Features" then reinstall using wsl --install. See steps here https://stackoverflow.com/a/79015013/1027250
